# javascript to test valid Email Address

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have this code that let the system test for the valid email address for inputs using "email: true". it works in the first try after clicking the save button, however on the next ones, upon entering single character WITHOUT CLICKING the save button yet, it already test for the input and shows the error message already

```
  $("#RoleConfigForm").validate({
            rules: {

                "group_code[]": {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 25,
                },
                "role_name[]": {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 25,
                },

                "email_address[]": {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    maxlength: 30,


                },
            },
            errorClass: "invalid",
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                $('#ResultDialog p').html("@hmis_resources.Message.msg_empty_fields");
                $('#ResultDialog').modal();
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                ajaxFormSubmit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: that is the behaviour of jquery validate. until email is not correct it will show error message

Comment: are there ways to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lazy" versus "Eager" validation.

jQuery Validate is "Lazy", so what you observe is the normal default behavior.

[As per the docs here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-validation-event):

> By default, forms are validated on submit, triggered by the user clicking the submit button or pressing enter when a form input is focused (option onsubmit). In addition, once a field was highlighted as being invalid, it is validated whenever the user types something in the field (option `onkeyup`). When the user enters something invalid into a valid field, it is also validated when the field loses focus (option <s>`onblur`</s> `onfocusout`).

[And here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo):

> - Before a field is marked as invalid, **the validation is lazy**: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages – they won't get bugged before having the chance to actually enter a correct value

---

**EDIT**:

To disable keyup and onblur validation entirely...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: false,
    ....
```

The form will only validate when the button is clicked.

Comment: is there a workaround to prevent this?

Comment: @rickyProgrammer, see edited answer.

Comment: onkeyup: false works! thanks!